# Using try-with-resources in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, try-with-resources

I have a try-catch statement in a Java servlet class. Netbeans shows an error on this:

> try-with-resources is not supported in -source 1.6
>   (use -source 7 or higher to enable try-with-resources)

How can I get rid of this error?

Comment: I got the error to go away. 

Right click on project > Properties > Sources > Source/Binary Format: JDK 7 > OK.

Comment: That's true, [try catch with resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) is supported by JDK 1.7 or higher, for versions 1.6 or lower you have to use normal try catch blocks :-). Moreover, since  you had found the answer to your question, Please do write this as an answer and accept your own answer, when the SYSTEM allows you to do that, for further assistance of someone who might face the same issue and visit this thread of yours. And do provide in your tags, which IDE you are using Eclipse, NetBeans or blah blah for a good assistance :-)

Comment: Your Welcome and Keep Smiling :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you found my thread from the NetBeans forums, in which I posted the solution:

> I got the error to go away.
>
> Right click on project > Properties > Sources > Source/Binary Format:
>   JDK 7 > OK.

Source:

- Error: "try-with-resources is not supported in -source 6 (use -source 7 or higher to enable try-with-resources)":

  http://forums.netbeans.org/ntopic42154.html

Answer (score 0):

Ok it didn't work for me. Because in "Source/Binary Format:" there isn't "JDK 7".

My solution was: Right click on project > Properties > Libraries > Manage Plataforms > Add Plataform, and choose your "jdk1.7.0_45" directory click on NEXT put a name "JDK 1.7" and FINISH.

Now you can modify your source format: Right click on project > Properties > Sources > Source/Binary Format: JDK 7 > OK.